# Angular Cookies does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I'm using `Angular v1.3.10` and i'm setting a cookie successfully.
When i'm doing `$cookieStore.put(key,value)` and then `$cookieStore.get(key)` i see the object I added.

When i'm refreshing the page and doing `$cookieStore.get(key)` i get undefined.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Did you try binding it to $scope? Something like $scope.myCookie = $cookieStore.get(key)?

Comment: If you don't add an expiration date the cookies do not persist

Answer (score 2):

At first appearance seems correct.

This works for me (version 1.3.0):

```
$cookieStore.put('MyVar', $scope.myVar); 
// After refresh
$scope.myVar = $cookieStore.get('MyVar');
```

On the other hand, [you can see](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) in documentation that $cookieStore is deprecated. You must use $cookies. It's very similar.

Good luck!